# Extract a specific word within a string

Tags: sql, oracle, text-extraction

I have a table called `HEADER`, within the table is a specific field called `SUMMARY`.

Summary contains an overview of an incident like this fake example:

```
TYPE: CUSTOMER 1
Address: ,123 S 3456 E,,FAIRYLAND,UT 12345-6789 USA
SITE: 1234-NEVADA-46789
Device Name: ROUTER
INCIDENT TYPE: Down
INCIDENT START TIME: 2022-02-10T08:32:25Z
```

What I am trying, and failing to do is extract only "Down" after the "INCIDENT TYPE:" line and add this as a new field call "INC_TYPE"

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a new line character after the incident type then you can just use a simple capture group:

```
select h.*,
  regexp_substr(h.summary, 'INCIDENT TYPE: (.*)', 1, 1, null, 1) as inc_type
from header h
```

Based on your example that is probably what you need; but if the values might all be on one line then you can restrict the match based on the following field (assuming that is always there), and including newlines in the match with the 'n' flag:

```
select h.*,
  regexp_substr(h.summary, 'INCIDENT TYPE: (.*)INCIDENT START TIME:', 1, 1, 'n', 1) as inc_type
from header h
```

... though that will leave the newline character or space as part of the `inc_type`, so you would probably want to trim that off:

```
select h.*,
  rtrim(
    regexp_substr(h.summary, 'INCIDENT TYPE: (.*)INCIDENT START TIME:', 1, 1, 'n', 1),
    chr(32)||chr(13)||chr(10) -- trim trailing space, newline, carriage return
  ) as inc_type
from header h
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9577a8935b224330ae8eb963dd3f5161)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT HEADER.*, REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUMMARY, 'INCIDENT TYPE: (.*) INCIDENT START TIME:', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS INC_TYPE
FROM HEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with the multi-line flag to ensure that you match from the start of each line:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^INCIDENT TYPE:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'm', 1)
         AS inc_type
FROM   header;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE header (summary) AS
SELECT 'TYPE: CUSTOMER 1
Address: ,123 S 3456 E,,FAIRYLAND,UT 12345-6789 USA
SITE: 1234-NEVADA-46789
Device Name: ROUTER
INCIDENT TYPE: Down
INCIDENT START TIME: 2022-02-10T08:32:25Z' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | INC_TYPE |
> | --- |
> | Down |

and:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^TYPE:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'im', 1) AS type,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^ADDRESS:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'im', 1) AS address,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^SITE:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'im', 1) AS site,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^DEVICE NAME:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'im', 1)
         AS device_name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^INCIDENT TYPE:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'im', 1)
         AS inc_type,
       TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, '^INCIDENT START TIME:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, 'im', 1),
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZR'
       ) AS incident_start_time
FROM   header;
```

Outputs:

> | TYPE | ADDRESS | SITE | DEVICE_NAME | INC_TYPE | INCIDENT_START_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | CUSTOMER 1 | ,123 S 3456 E,,FAIRYLAND,UT 12345-6789 USA | 1234-NEVADA-46789 | ROUTER | Down | 2022-02-10 08:32:25.000000000 +00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed9901630b8dd1090ecb7031655484ca)*